# Android Activity back navigation recursive loop issue

Tags: android, android-activity, recursion

I have three activities A,B,C.
A being the parent activity. The navigation is supposed to be A---> B ---> C --->B----C---> B (Its a loop for B and C).
The issue i'm facing is in the back navigation, which is supposed to be as shown in the image.
Back from B should always go back to parent A and back from C should always go back to B. But sometimes B goes back to C which is resulting in a recursive loop between B and C. Can anyone help me out? 
Here is what I have tried:

```
ACTIVITY A
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent.putExtra("A",true);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);



ACTIVITY B
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
intent.putExtra("A",true);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();

OnBackpressed B
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();


ACTIVITY C
Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, B.class);
intent.putExtra("A",A);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();


OnBackpressed C

if(A){
Intent iu= new Intent(C.this,B.class);
iu.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
iu.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(iu);
finish();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not able to understand why you are trying this for? But anyways you can override the onBackPressed() method to make it customized specifically for your Activity in your Android Application.

Answer (score 1):

1-Go from A to B without using finish()

```
2-Go from B to c without using finish()

3-Go from c to B using finish() in 
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       finish();
    }

 4-Go from B to A using finish() in 
    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
           finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating several instances of `Activity C` and `Activity B`. That should not happen. There should be only one instance of each `activity`. You need to call `finish()` methods appropriately.
Instead of calling `startActivity()`, you can call `startActivityForResult()` and get this done easily.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is override the `onBackPressed` functionality for your activities, something like this:

for Activity B:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //start activity A
    }
```

for Activity C:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //start activity B
    }
```